# I am Chinese. How can I get Swedish visa in USA?

Tags: visas, usa, sweden, chinese-citizens

I am Chinese.
I am going to school in the USA. How can I get Swedish visa in USA?

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Could you clarify what you mean? Do you mean a Swedish passport visa (ie you are Swedish too) or is there some other meaning to this?

Comment: I think he is asking for a (tourist?) visa to enter Sweden, being a Chinese citizen with a US student visa and living in the US.

Comment: Ah! That makes a bit more sense now!

Answer (score 9):

You'll have to [apply for a visa](http://www.swedenabroad.com/en-GB/Embassies/Washington/Visit-Sweden/Visa-Information/) - it can be done online if certain requirements are met. Otherwise, you may have to visit the [embassy or one of the consulates](http://www.swedenabroad.com/en-GB/Embassies/Washington/Contact/Embassy--Consulates/) of Sweden in the USA. They should also be able to answer questions authoritatively.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, you have to be able to prove your residency in the country where you apply the visa (in the US for your case).
Since you are a student, then it should be easy for you since you have a Student Visa / Resident card.
But as always, the safer is to just ask the concerned embassy.